# Using pending intents with sms manager - Handling run time changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

I'm using a pending intent with sms manager. Similar to this [link](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/10/smsmessage-delivery-in-android-with.html#.U2T8NPmSyL0)

My doubt is how we handle run time changes like orientation change, receiving a call etc.

I read in some places that when we use broadcast receivers, we need to unregister and register them again. But we need pending intent of previously sent SMS

There are two other options:

1. Start as a service
2. Use a fragment and use setRetainInstance(true)

Which method is standard practice and preferable?

Comment: Any comments please :)